# How to change one material to another with effect Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

How to get this effect. Replacing one material is not a problem. How to do it with such an effect?
[Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N7xRi3weE9_sIrtGY2i5elH1a1GxrDsm/view?usp=share_link)

I'll be glad for any hints.

Thank you

I thought I could do it with a mask, but it didn't work.

Comment: This effect can be achieved by using shaders. I used it before but I don't actually know how it's implemented. At least I can give you a point to start.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that it is a material replacement shown in the video. More looks like a material that is white and can become colored from the point and radius around it.

Answer (score 0):

As says on comments that its *shader magic*. Many people think shaders are just fancy graphics but they're fairly complex and will require some technical knowledge before and learning not only a new language, but a brand new KIND of programming languages, so I will not recommend jump into that if you are not already confident with c#.

However, if you want to dip your feet in that cold waters you can take a look at https://thebookofshaders.com